# My result is not getting saved as an ouput in jupyter notebook yet

Tags: python, deep-learning

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from skimage.io import imread, imshow
import cv2


%matplotlib inline
import plotly.offline as py
py.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.tools as tls

from subprocess import check_output
from subprocess import call
print(os.listdir("C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\input\\train"))
print(check_output(["ls", "../input"]).decode("utf8"))
```

The output is not getting saved.

[Following are the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0x0rM.png)

[Following is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihQJi.png)

Comment: Do you have the `ls` command on your system? (As this is windows I doubt it) NB. even if you had it, I doubt "../input" would work.

Comment: Oh actually i am new to this could you guide what alternate cmd I can use (and yes it's windows)

Comment: I'm not familiar with windows. You should probably rework your question to remove everything that is not needed (all the plotting stuff) and clearly explain what you try to achieve (listing files?). I guess you should actually be able to find already existing answers (in which case, just delete your question).

Comment: Okay. Yes I got my mistake since you mentioned about those difference of linux. I typed the dir command and it works! Thank you